# Preserving supercompactness in intermediate forcing extensions

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be supercompact in $V$. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be one of the standard forcing notions (or an iteration of such), and for simplicity assume that $\mathbb{P}$ is ${<}\kappa$-directed closed (e.g. a $\kappa$-Hechler iteration). In particular, $\kappa$ will remain supercompact in $V^{\mathbb{P}}$ if $V$ was 'Laver prepared'.

Question: What conditions can we impose on $\mathbb{P}$ and $V$ such that $\kappa$ remains supercompact in every intermediate forcing extension, i.e. $V \vDash \forall \mathbb{Q} \triangleleft \mathbb{P} \, \colon \, \Vdash_{\mathbb{Q}} \check{\kappa} \, \text{is supercompact}$ ?

Comment: It is likely hard to say much. Results of Kunen show that if $\mathbb{P}$ is even just the forcing to add a single Cohen real to $\kappa$, there is an intermediate extension where $\kappa$ isn't even weakly compact.

Comment: @Miha: Cohen subset, perchance? Also, can you give a reference, that seems interesting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I meant Cohen subset of $\kappa$. Kunen showed that if you first add a Suslin tree to $\kappa$ and then force with the tree to kill it, the iteration is equivalent to adding a single Cohen subset to $\kappa$. Of course, in the intermediate model the Suslin tree kills weak compactness, but if $\kappa$ was sufficiently indestructible to being with, a lot of strength can be resurrected by killing the tree. I think this first appeared in his [Saturated ideals paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2271949), but it's been written up many times since then.

Comment: @Miha: Ohhh, yes. Of course. I had that in mind, but for some reason I didn't connect that to the resurrection of weak compactness. Thanks!

Comment: Related to Kunen's result: [Large cardinals need not be large in HOD](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016800721500069X?via%3Dihub)

Comment: @Johannes: But Cohen forcing is the most ${<}\kappa$-directed closed forcing you can possibly imagine. It is in fact ${<}\kappa$-lattice, so that not only it is directed closed, but every small directed set has an infimum.

Comment: Here’s another example. If GCH holds in the neighborhood, then for a regular $\kappa$, there is a two-step iteration $\mathbb S * \mathbb T$ that adds a $\square_\kappa$-sequence and then threads it, and the iteration is isomorphic to $\mathsf{Col}(\kappa,\kappa^+)$.

Comment: @Asaf: Sorry I was being silly. I mistook the forcing adding a $\kappa$-Cohen real with the forcing adding $\kappa$ many Cohen reals (on $\omega$). I also misread a definition in Apter's paper...
Okay, this actually resolves my question!

Comment: @Johannes: That's why I asked Miha to clarify that "Cohen real" meant Cohen subset.